# Power BI: Multiple condition in single if condition

Tags: powerbi

I have table with the fields `Amount, Condition1, Condition2`.

Example:

```
Amount  Condition1   Condition2
----------------------------------
123     Yes          Yes
234     No           Yes
900     Yes          No
```

I want to calculate the 20% of the amount based on condition:

If both `Condition1` and `Condition2` is Yes then calculate `20%` else `0`.

**My try**: I tried with conditional custom column but unable to add `AND` in `IF` in the query editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a conditional column like this:

```
= IF(AND(Table1[Condition1] = "Yes", Table1[Condition2] = "Yes"), 0.2 * Table1[Amount], 0)
```

Or you can use `&&` instead of the `AND` function:

```
= IF(Table1[Condition1] = "Yes" && Table1[Condition2] = "Yes", 0.2 * Table1[Amount], 0)
```

Or an even shorter version using concatenation:

```
= IF(Table1[Condition1] & Table1[Condition2] = "YesYes", 0.2 * Table1[Amount], 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a new calculated column.
And Use below DAX query:

```
new_column = IF(Conditition1 = "Yes", IF(Condititon2 = "Yes",Amt * 0.2 ,0), 0)
```